# assertRaises not getting matched

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing

I'm learning python unitesting and wanted to test for exception handling. Why assertRaises is not getting caught and my unittest gets failed ?

```
def abc(xyz):
    print xyz
    try:
        raise RuntimeError('I going to raise exception')
    except ValueError, e:
        print e
    except RuntimeError, e:
        print e
    except Exception, e:
        print e


import unittest

class SimplisticTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        with self.assertRaises(RuntimeError):
            abc(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()



2
F
I going to raise exception
======================================================================
FAIL: test_1 (__main__.SimplisticTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/d066537/ClionProjects/pythonspark/sample.py", line 18, in test_1
    abc(2)
AssertionError: RuntimeError not raised

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Why the test fails and how to correct it.
Whats the problem with this one:

```
def abc(xyz):
    print xyz
    raise ValueError('I going to raise exception')




import unittest

class SimplisticTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, abc(2), msg="Exception not getting caught")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

2
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_1 (__main__.SimplisticTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/d066537/ClionProjects/pythonspark/sample.py", line 12, in test_1
    self.assertRaises(ValueError, abc(2), msg="Exception not getting caught")
  File "/home/d066537/ClionProjects/pythonspark/sample.py", line 3, in abc
    raise ValueError('I going to raise exception')
ValueError: I going to raise exception

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: You are raising RunTimeError but catching it few lines later.

Comment: Whats the problem with my 2nd example

Comment: You are trying to catch ValueError, but it's not raised anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it doesn't raise it; the exception is caught and dealt with inside the function.

In the second example, you call the function and pass the result to assertRaises, so the exception happens before assertRaises can catch it. You should use the context manager approach as you do in the first example, or pass the callable: `self.assertRaises(ValueError, abc, 2, msg=...)`.

Comment: Whats the problem with the second example.